# Mudar valor de variável de script via aplicação Java

Tags: java, linux, script, shell

Criei um script onde dentro desse *script* há um laço do tipo `while`. A condição de para desse `while` é `escolha != 1`. Tudo funciona ok, porém no meio desse `while` eu executo uma aplicação Java onde faço algumas verificações e dependendo dessa verificação preciso alterar o valor dessa variável escolha para 1 para poder sair do laço. Há alguma forma de fazer isso? Eu tentei dessa forma:

[image: SS]
[image: SS]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em português @FernandoL. É preferível postar mesmo o código relevante na sua pergunta ao invés de *screen shots* do código. Para escrever código na sua pergunta deixe `4 espaços` antes de começar a escrever, ou cole o código e enquanto selecionado clique no botão **`{}`** que se encontra acima do editor. Podes também ler mais sobre como formatar o texto de uma publicação em: [**Ajuda na edição**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

No *script* você fará isto:

```
retorno = $(java -jar VerificaSolucao.jar $numCorA A)
```

Use a variável `retorno` no `if`.

No Java você vai mudar a linha onde você tenta mudar uma variável que não existe lá e [retorna o valor desejado](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-). No `else` você fará isto:

```
System.exit(1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/Exit.java).

Não esqueça de sinalizar o 0 no `if`, afinal você sempre deverá sinalizar algo, não importa como o Java execute. Eu não sei se o Java enviar o 0 por padrão se não sinalizar nada.

Na verdade a convenção é retorna 0 quando tudo funciona bem e um número negativo quando há algum problema.

Eu colocaria o código todo se você tivesse postado ele ao invés de imagem.

Comment: Obrigado, desse jeito funcionou.

Comment: @FernandoL. dê uma lida nisso para entender o funcionamento do site: [tour].